# How to underline onclick and add to textarea

Tags: javascript

I have this code that enables the users to add a list of keywords to a text area and than submit it. The list will show on a div, then the user has to select one or many words in one line to add it to **id="out"**.
The code is working as of now, but it's not what I want and I'm blocked. What I want is that the user can click (instead of select) one or many words to underline them and then click on the image to add them as a line to **id="out"**.
 I've big trouble to solve this as my JS knowledge is very limited, but I hope to learn quickly by working on similar projects and I've a lot in mind.

Thank you

Code:

```js
var arraySearchTerms = [];

function add() {
  arraySearchTerms = document.getElementById("searchTerms").value.split('\n');
  let newKeywordHtmlStr = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < arraySearchTerms.length; i++) {
    newKeywordHtmlStr += '<div style="padding: 6px;border-bottom: #b5aeae; border-bottom-style: solid;border-bottom-width: 1px;"><span id="term' + i + '">' + arraySearchTerms[i] + "</span><span style='float: right;'><img src='Red_Cross.png' height='15' width='11'/></span></div>";
  }
  document.getElementById("keywords").innerHTML += newKeywordHtmlStr;
}


function get_selection() {
  var txt = '';  
  if (window.getSelection) {
    txt = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection) {
    txt = document.selection.createRange().keywords;
  }
  document.getElementById("out").innerHTML += txt;
}
```

```html
<TITLE>Test</TITLE>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="negative.css">

<div id="container">
  <div id="container2">
    Add your search terms:
    <textarea type="text" id="searchTerms">
    </textarea> <br />
    <button onclick="add()">Add >></button><br />
    <br /><br /> Negative keywords:
    <textarea type="text" id="out"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div id="container1">
    Search terms:
    <div id="keywords" onclick="get_selection()"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="negative.js"></script>
```

Comment: please share a fiddle for this

Comment: It's not working on fiddle, unfortunately :(

Comment: @Aravind S You can find a working preview under my post.

Comment: `id` should be unique, you cant add the same `id` many time, example is `term0`

Comment: I add as many ids as the number of lines on the user input. I have only one term0 <span id="term' + i + '">

Comment: check and let me know whether this is what you need http://jsfiddle.net/Aravi/s167qd03/4/

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you've just made the script able to add a new selection to the id="out". I'm not there yet and I know how to solve that. Thank anyway for your help. What I want to do is click on a word or many words in the same line, underline them, and add them as a new line to id="out" when the user is decided and he clicks on the image (not displayed in the preview but present in the code)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176032/discussion-between-aravind-s-and-creek-barbara).